# Dependency problems creating Jersey client in AbstractInstallerScreen

Tags: java, install4j

In our Install4j-project we wanted to perform a call to our webserver using Jersey. We implemented an AbstractInstallAction for this task, that calls the server using

```
Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
```

This works fine in the CustomAction; now i wanted to use the same code in an AbstractInstallerScreen; the call of the same code line in the screen causes the following exception (i shortened the log entry, but i think you will get the point):

```
Oct 06, 2016 10:10:24 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  ...
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: com.sun.jersey.spi.MessageBodyWorkers com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider.bodyWorker
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:683)
   ...
```

In my POM-file i load the jersey dependencies using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So the question is: how should i make the call in the installer screen so that i don't get the exception saying missing dependencies, or what is the difference in using jersey in a custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to JAX-WS's misuse of the context class loader.

In scripts and actions, install4j temporarily resets the context class loader for this very reason, but in screens and form components, this does not happen.

If you call your code like that:

```
ClassLoader oldContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    // TODO Add your code that uses JAX-WS
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldContextClassLoader);
}
```

it should work.

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you!